# How to put a script that calls itself in a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I try to execute this code :

index.html :

```
<div id="mydiv">test</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#mydiv').html('<script type="text/javascript" id="myscript" src="test.js"><\/script>');
</script>
```

test.js :

```
alert(document.getElementById('myscript').src);
```

I have this error :

```
document.getElementById("myscript") is null
```

I would like to resolve it, knowing that `"'<script type="text/javascript" id="myscript" src="test.js"></script>'"` is obtained by an ajax call, mixed with others contents, but I simplified the code for the example.

Comment: Is test.js the same as script.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `document.CreateElement` and `document.body.appendChild` to make your script tag available to getElementById . you can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9902803/getelementbyid-where-element-is-dynamically-created-at-runtime)

in your case it could be

```
var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');

scriptTag.src = 'test.js';

document.getElementByID("mydiv").appendChild(scriptTag);
```

Comment: I do this :

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#mydiv').html('<div id="mydiv2"></div><script type="text/javascript">var scriptTag = document.createElement(\'script\');scriptTag.src = \'test.js\';scriptTag.id = \'myscript\';document.getElementById("mydiv2").appendChild(scriptTag);<\/script>');
    </script>

Answer (score 0):

I think the tag would have to be closed before you can query inside of it. So your `test.js` script would have to wait a split second, DOM-ready, or window.onload.