# Nodes are already added into the dom tree, but still get null using getElementById

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried these two methods of adding a DOM node dynamically:

```
var myTable = "<table id=\"myLeftTable\">" + "<tr><th id=\"univName\">Name</th><th id=\"satHigh\">SAT High</th><th id=\"satLow\">SAT Low</th><th id=\"tuition\">Tuition</th></tr>";
myTable = myTable + "<tr class=\"even\">" + "<td>" + cur.nickname +"</td>" + "<td>" + cur.SATh + "</td>" + "<td>" + cur.SATl + "</td>" + "<td>" + "$" + parseInt(cur.tuition).toFixed(0).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") + "</td>" + "<tr>" ;
```

and

```
var newTR = document.createElement("tr");
newTR.setAttribute("class","even")
var newTD1 = document.createElement("td");
var newText1 = document.createTextNode(cur.nickname);
newTD1.appendChild(newText1);
```

When I run this, I can see new nodes added to the tree when I inspect element (if this is the right way to see). I tried to add a click handler on the heading to sort that column on a user click. But when I use

```
document.getElementById("univName")
```

(univName is the `id` in one the table headers above, and I can see from the tree that it has this id) But I still get null error.

Could someone please tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Is `document.getElementById("univName")` beig called after DOM is updated ?

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9902803/getelementbyid-where-element-is-dynamically-created-at-runtime

Comment: Sorry if I confused you by not pasting the whole program. I did have that document.getElementById("somediv").innerHTML = myTable for the first solution.

Comment: And for the second solution, I have the header that has an id named "univName", I just didn't paste that part. But still, when I call getElementById("univName"), I get null error.

Comment: @AliTurki, Thanks! The reason I have the second solution is because I followed the solution in this link and changed my solution from the first one to second one. But neither works, I'm so frustrated now.

Answer (score 0):

In your first solution, you are not inserting that HTML into the DOM anywhere.

In your second solution, you are not creating an element with the id of `univName`

Taking your first solution, I've added a line for inserting the HTML into a `div` (you'll want to replace the `document.getElementById('some-div')` with whichever DOM node you are trying to insert the table). I've also added a click handler on your `univName` header, so try running the snippet below, and clicking on the header.

```js
// Just some dummy data for the snippet to run.
var cur = {
  nickname: 'nickname',
  tuition: 12023,
  SATh: 1500,
  SATl: 1000,
}

var myTable = "<table id=\"myLeftTable\">" + "<tr><th id=\"univName\">Name</th><th id=\"satHigh\">SAT High</th><th id=\"satLow\">SAT Low</th><th id=\"tuition\">Tuition</th></tr>";
myTable = myTable + "<tr class=\"even\">" + "<td>" + cur.nickname +"</td>" + "<td>" + cur.SATh + "</td>" + "<td>" + cur.SATl + "</td>" + "<td>" + "$" + parseInt(cur.tuition).toFixed(0).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") + "</td>" + "<tr>" ;

// Attach the table to `some-div`.
// Replace this with your own DOM selector
document.getElementById('some-div').innerHTML = myTable;


// We can access `univName` now.

document.getElementById('univName').addEventListener('click', 
  function(e){
    console.log('It works!');
  });
```

```html
<div id="some-div"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your solution, the above is part of my code since it's really long. I did have that line and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks again and I have found the problem. Sorry for confusing you, I should probably paste all the important parts of the program next time when I ask questions.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I get what's wrong. 
So the problem is that I have two events:

```
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", createTable, false);
```

and

```
document.getElementById("univName").addEventListener("click", sort, false);
```

So if you don't click the button and trigger the first one which will create the element that has id "univName", you won't get the "univName" element, but the program will still go to the second one and couldn't find that id.

This can be solved by moving the second line into the  "createTable" function.

I'm still quite new to javascript (this is the second time I programmed in js ). I guess this is really a careless and mistake.

Thank you for anyone who tried to help.