# Cant find input by id after added with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So `onclick` i add a textbox to one of my `<p>` tag and it works well, gets the css and all, but when i try to get its value it seems like it cant find it by `document.getElementById("someting")`, because it says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of null

I typed in stuff, but it cant find it.

I think the problem is because the input doesnt exist when the page is loaded, and it wont find it if its added after.

```
onclick = document.getElementById("something").innerHTML = <input id='myInput' class='textbox' autofocus value=''>

var inputvalue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
```

Comment: F.Y.I. `someting` and `something` is not same. Check code for the typo.

Comment: The code you posted is not valid JavaScript - you cannot put raw HTML inside a JavaScript and then assign it to `.innerHTML`. Also, avoid `innerHTML` because it invokes the parser, instead you should prefer the DOM manipulation API instead (`document.createElement`, etc).

Comment: Invalid code. Is `onclick` supposed to be a function? It is not. Did you want an `=>`?

Comment: where do you put that? it's not a correct javascript syntax

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of null` suggests something completely different than not being able to find the element. At some point you do `someVariable.document` and `someVariable` is `null`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getElementById Where Element is dynamically created at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9902803/getelementbyid-where-element-is-dynamically-created-at-runtime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you are not creating and inserting element to the DOM.

you should do it through `document.createElement` and append it to the DOM!

you can see the solution through link below

[getElementById Where Element is dynamically created at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9902803/getelementbyid-where-element-is-dynamically-created-at-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

Use this approach with the help of jQuery:
for example we assume that you want to add this html to a div:

```
 $('#div').append('<input id='myInput' class='textbox' autofocus value=''>');
```

Then:

```
var value = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
```