# Extract data from dynamically created rows in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have found many solutions to this problem with jQuery, but I am not allowed to use jQuery for this problem, only javascript. I create rows dynamically in an HTML defined table and I need to extract the data from, for example, the name and the index of the selected row when I click on a button. Each row has its own button. Below is a part of my code. Any help is welcome!

```
Name=document.getElementById("name").value;
index=document.getElementById("index").value;
phone=document.getElementById("phone").value;

var newRow=table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
var newCell0=newRow.insertCell(0);
newCell0.innerHTML=Name;

var newCell1=newRow.insertCell(1);
newCell1.innerHTML=index;

var newCell2=newRow.insertCell(2);
newCell2.innerHTML=phone;
```

Comment: are you using jquery?

Comment: I am a student and for this type of exercise, I am not allowed to use jQuery, only javascript.

Answer (score 0):

try this solution

```
window.onload = function(){
//access your dynamic element normally here
};
```

and you can find relevant solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9902803/getelementbyid-where-element-is-dynamically-created-at-runtime#:~:text=To%20add%20an%20element%20using,need%20to%20do%202%20things.&text=If%20a%20DOM%20node%20is,be%20used%20anywhere%20within%20scope.)

Answer (score 0):

pop this into your HTML:

```
<table id="output-table"></table>
```

then you can create table rows and insert cells in JavaScript:

```
var outputTable = document.getElementById("output-table");

function addRows () {

var newRow = outputTable.insertRow();
var newCell = newRow.insertCell;

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

    var newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
    newCell.innerHTML = "Cell";
}
console.log(newRow);
```

}

From here you should be able to do what you need.
Hope it helps.