# Check is external Javascript has changed or not

Tags: javascript, browser, getelementbyid

Here is my code which might not be the best solution of my problem, and my goal is to check the external script  (**script.js**) every 2 seconds if it's code has changed. If it is changed, then execute it.

```
function connectLoader(retval) {
    console.log('Executing...');
    var old = document.getElementById("EPMagic");
    if (old !== null) {
      old.outerHTML = "";
      delete old; 
    }

    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('id','EPMagic');
    script.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
    script.setAttribute('src','http://server.com/script.js');
    head.appendChild(script);
}
setInterval('connectLoader()',2000);
```

The problem is that /script.js is still executed even if it is not being changed.
The code on **/script.js** is simply `alert('Execute');`

Comment: First you can verify by inspecting your page and see if the script tag is added or not to the HTML.

Comment: [It should work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9902827/1264804). Are you showing us everything relevant?

Comment: Are you expecting the reference to find the element after it already ran? The line `document.getElementById("loadScript");` does not keep checking the DOM, it is once and done.

Answer (score 0):

Use setAttribue to set the attributes values:

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute('id','loadScript');
script.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
script.setAttribute('src','http://server.ip/script.js');
head.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Setting the attributes still doesn't help.

Comment: What is the content of http://server.ip/script.js ?
If you place there <script> tag - it won't work, it should be pure JavaScript.
ie. only 
alert(1);

Comment: Edit: So it works with pure JavaScript as long as you don't use documentElement.innerHTML=String.fromCharCode(104, 116, 109, 108...)
I want to use the following method as it renders HTML

Comment: You've loaded external JavaScript file to the DOM.
Now, what do you wish to achieve that doesn't work?

Comment: ```
var old = document.getElementById("loadScript");
if (old !== null) {
   old.outerHTML = "";
   delete old;
```
Any idea why this doesn't work?

Comment: If, I understand right, you've loaded external JavaScript file and expect it to be gone, after removing the script tag that include it.
It doesn't work this way, as the JavaScript was already executed to the browser's memory.
you will have to delete the objects that this script created.

Comment: Yes, you got the idea, however what do you offer as an alternative solution? I have been referring to this code: https://vulners.com/exploitpack/EXPLOITPACK:73ADFD1BB6F9219093DC352B9CE15A48